# Chinese character, wa in pinyin, meaning to jump

Tags: characters

In the martial arts form known as Liuhebafa, there are eight external methods. The seventh method is Wa Qian “Jumping and Bridging.” The Chinese character for “bridging” is, I think, 橋. But I can’t figure out what the Chinese character, pronounced Wa, is, meaning "to jump." Is there a Chinese character, pronounced Wa in pinyin, that means “to jump”?

Comment: Where do you see the words "Wa Qian"? The possible translation is "挖墙(wā qiáng)", which means digging walls. Liuhebafa quan (六合八法拳) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liuhebafa

Answer (score 1):

I think it is 跨 /Kuà/

[跨](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/2791) means "step across" but when you 跨過 something and at a point both your feet are off the ground, 跨過 is qualified as "jump across"

Think of 跨欄賽跑 (hurdle race), the motion of "stepping over"(跨過) the hurdles is actually "jumping over" them (in a stepping motion)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my continuing search before returning to StackExchanage, I found this: The Eight External Methods: 1. 起落　2. 動靜　3.進退　4. 開合　5. 陰陽　6. 虛实　7. 跃远　8. 六合 . . . Everything seems to tally with the quote I found in a book except 7 where  跃 is yuè and 远 is yuǎn,  but the book has Wa qiao. The book offers no Chinese characters, only the Pinyin. Note: the "Wa qiao" is in a book called Liuhebafa Five Character Secrets by Paul Dillon, p. 42.

Comment: 跃远 can be Wa Tiao 蛙跳